# How to remove extra div of empty JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I'm using JSON array data to display content on a HTML page using JavaScript & jQuery but it results in a div of empty content and I don't think I'm adding it with my a code and I don't know how to remove it. Is anyone aware of what is wrong here? All suggestions are much appreciated!

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
  <img src="images/cn-header.jpg" alt="logo" />
</div>

<div id="container">
  <div class="article">
    <div class="title-home"></div>
    <div class="cover-home"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("article.json", function(data){
    console.log(data) //just to log in console as well
    var article_data = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
      article_data += '<div class="article">';
      article_data += '<div class="title-home">' + value.title + '</div>';
      article_data += '<div class="cover-home"> <img src="' + value.cover + '"> </div>';
      article_data += '</div>';
    });
    $('#container').append(article_data);
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
}
.article {
  padding: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  /*border: 1px solid red;*/
}
.title-home {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.cover-home {
  border: 5px solid green;
}
.cover-home img {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's the first div in your html, which is empty, just delete it, now the code should be : `<div id="container"></div>`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the contents of your container div:

```
<div id="header"> 
  <img src="images/cn-header.jpg" alt="logo" />
</div>

<!-- #containet div now empty -->
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: So simple! Thank you!

Comment: Glad you found my answer useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Use and [`if` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) to conditionally run a block of commands in JavaScript.

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
  if (value.title != '') {
    article_data += '<div class="article">';
    article_data += '<div class="title-home">' + value.title + '</div>';
    article_data += '<div class="cover-home"> <img src="' + value.cover + '"> </div>';
    article_data += '</div>';
  }
});
```

Adjust the condition based on how you expect your data.

You check what your data actually looks like with `console.log` or inspecting the Networks tab of your browser, if you're fetching it from a server.

Answer (score 0):

KIndly check if both parameters are having some value in response.

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
    var isTrue = value.title!='' && value.cover!='';
      if (isTrue ) {
        article_data += '<div class="article">';
        article_data += '<div class="title-home">' + value.title + '</div>';
        article_data += '<div class="cover-home"> <img src="' + value.cover + '"> </div>';
        article_data += '</div>';
      }
    });
```